Is there a way to change the To or Bcc email in Azure DevOps Group Notifications
Basically if you send a Group Notification, the To Address includes all members. I am looking for a way if it can just show the member receiving it.
Or maybe if there is a way I can change from To to Bcc which should accomplish the same thing.
I tried setting it to 'Individual Members' but the behavior is the same.

In a team environment, there is often a need to know which members have received notifications in order to better coordinate and collaborate. If "Bcc" is used, this information may be hidden, which may be detrimental to team collaboration. I think this is probably why email notifications are designed this way.
However, this does not mean that "Bcc" is not required in all cases. In some cases, such as when a large number of recipients are involved or recipient privacy needs to be protected, "Bcc" may be a better choice.
However, Azure DevOps currently does not support the feature to change the "To" field to "Bcc" in a group notification.  You can request a feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better.

Thank you! We used JIRA in the past and it works like this so we're trying to do the same in DevOps. We prefer the 'To' address have a single user as when it has multiple, users tend to hit 'Reply' to the email rather than logging into the system and updating the workitem/ticket.
I will make a  request in Azure DevOps developer community, however, in the mean time, we will probably have to setup user notifications individually which will be tedious (will also probably try and script it to save some time).

Hi @ajbear, thanks for your response. When users hit 'Reply' to the notification email directly, they will find it does not update the work item or ticket in the Azure DevOps. To update a work item or ticket, they need to log into the Azure DevOps and make the changes there.  Maybe after users get used to it, they won’t reply directly to notification emails. :) Happy coding!
